# Getting error when trying to upload file (HttpPostedFileBase) through Http Client C# mvc to another api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CommonConstants.ApiUrl);
    string UId = Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginId"]);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("LoginIDH", UId);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token_Header", Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthToken"]));

    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var stream = new StreamContent(PostedFile.InputStream);

        stream.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        stream.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = PostedFile.FileName };
        content.Add(stream, "import", PostedFile.FileName);

        var response = client.PostAsync(requesturi, content).Result;

    }
}
```

I am getting an error

> Unsupported media type in the response. Status Code: 415.

I need to upload the Excel file (`.xlsx` format)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the server doesn't accept the `Content-Type` you are providing `application/octet-stream`.

You should check with the API provider which value they are expecting. The most suitable type for the `.xlsx` format is:
`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types